# Best way to extract text from PDF in java

Tags: java, pdf, ocr, libraries, scanning

I want to make a program that is able to read PDF files and parse it's contents.
Thus I need to extract the text using some kind of library. I found 3 ways to do so.

1. OCR libraries (like Tesseract)
2. ScanPdf libraries (like iText)
3. Converters from PDF to text.

I fail to understand the big differences between them since all of them will produce in the end a text file from the PDF. So which is the best way to go about this?

Comment: If you want to read PDF files and extract contents then a library would be most appropriate. OCR would be more appropriate if your source documents were scanned from printed docs or images. A PDF to text converter would first parse the PDF and dump the text somewhere. That could be useful in a batch processing scenario. However using a good library like [Apache PDF Box](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) would help you do the read/parse/extract inside your program.

Comment: What exactly is the difference between your ways 2 and 3?

Comment: The one is a library so everything happens inside my program and the other is a plain program that runs before I mine to process the data

Answer (score 0):

PDF is a complex format. If you open a PDF and you're staring at a bunch of text, that doesn't really tell you much. It could be that you're staring at an image file someone decided to wrap into a PDF file. This is 99%+ certain what you have if someone scanned a document and told their scanner to 'scan to PDF', and 100% certain what you got if you have a PNG or JPG and 'save as PDF', or try to 'print to PDF' such a thing.

**There is no text in the PDF then**. There are pixels.

To turn pixels into text, that's where OCR libraries come in. That's what they do. That is all they do. It's an AI bonanza and error prone. No guarantees.

However, PDF is more complex than that, it isn't like PNG/JPG: It's more like HTML. You can put actual text in there.

This has different issues, though. You can place text blobs (i.e. a 'rectangle', with coordinates, and then the text that is supposed to go inside). Again a lot like HTML: You can do something like:

```
<p class="foo">
World!
</p>
<p class="bar">
Hello,
</p>
```

and then create CSS so that the `foo` is rendered **after** the `bar` block (can be as simple as `.foo, .bar { display: block; } .foo {float: right}`).

Turning that HTML into "World! Hello," is not all that tricky. Realizing that during a render, you end up seeing "Hello, World!", and thus writing code that returns "Hello, World!", that's way more complicated.

The same problem applies to PDF. For simple PDFs, extracting the raw text inside is not too difficult, but be aware that for even mildly complex PDFs, the text can arrive in a jumbled mess.

iText is trying to give you enough power, at least, to provide the latter: To give you a full hierarchical breakdown. It returns 'here is a text box, here is its positioning, and here is the text inside. and now here is another text box, etc'. It does not return a big string.

In other words: The answer depends a lot on what PDFs you have / what PDFs you expect to be able to read, and how complex they are. If they are scans, you need an OCR library. If they are simple, a basic pdf2text converter will do fine. If you want to attempt to take into account fancily positioned PDFs with forms inside and 'popups' that can be opened and closed, oof. Probably all these tools are insufficient and you're signing up to many personweeks worth of effort.

Answer (score 0):

There definitely IS text embedded PDFs, it is NOT just pixels.

It depends on if the PDF is a "true" PDF (ie you can highlight the text and copy and paste it elsewhere) or if the PDF is a scanned image.

With scanned images, you'll have to use an OCR API. All of the major cloud providers have OCR APIs (ie Amazon Textract, Google Document AI, Microsoft Form Recognizer, etc). If it's a true PDF, then I've found the pdf.js library (https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) quite helpful in doing a direct text extraction.

Just know that doing this only gets you the text that is literally on the page, and there's quite a bit of work still to do to get key/value data fields programmatically across many documents.

This is something that my startup is working on ([www.sensible.so/](http://www.sensible.so/)) too if you're interested in something more powerful!